# Jobs in powershell

Tags: multithreading, powershell, invoke-command

I am using ps-session to run a console application on a remote machine. I do not want to pass the control to the next statement until the console application is completely executed. How do I pass control over to the console application in powershell? Is multi-threading an option? Or Do I need to create Jobs for the same?

This is the command that I am using:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {Start-Process $args[0] -ArgumentList $args[1] -RedirectStandardOutput $args[2] -RedirectStandardError $args[3]} -Args $dir,$arguments,$stdOutLog,$stdErrLog;
```

here dir is the consoledirectory(D:\Temp\ConsoleApp.exe)

Also, If i use -wait command, the console application does get completely executed but the control never returns back to powershell.

Comment: `-wait` or -`passthru`, cant recall now

Comment: @4c74356b41 -wait does work but once the console application is completed, the control does not come back to the powershell application. -passthru does not work for me